# What is the correct MIME Type for JSON content?

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

I have problem with JSON is that it is only displaying " Content-Type: text/html" I am testing on localhost and my  online code is

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
//header('Content-type: text/javascript');
//header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: why do you not use `application/json`?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/1077789)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `application/json` header for JSON data:

```php
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: @user1709424 can you post some code??

Comment: <?php
require 'include/jamroom-include.inc.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


//header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
//content header
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
header('Content-type: text/*');
header('Content-type: application/*');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
header('Content-Type: text/x-javascript');
header('Content-Type: text/x-json');

Comment: why are you inserting this much of header only put this header `header('Content-type: application/json');
` for getting `json` output data.

Answer (score 1):

The `application/json` Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

chech this from [IANA](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

**good read:**

[Application Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The MIME type for JSON is `application/json`